# Line intersection check in LP constraints?

Tags: geometry, optimization, linear-programming

Assuming I have a set of lines each defined by two points and am somehow optimizing the position of these points, is it possible to create LP constraints that would prevent the lines from intersecting? Even some approximation with a certain error range?

Comment: This would not fully solve, but if you're okay with approximations, you just need to exclude that for any two lines, the four points that define these lines do not lie in the same hyperplane. This would exclude lines which are the in the same hyperplane but are parallel, so it would be a little stronger than what you would need. Naive implementation would require one constraint for each pair of lines.

Comment: What is an "LP constraint"?

Comment: @Jens linear programming constraint. Inequeality constraints with linear terms